# Displaying content in draft mode

Tags: views, nodes, workflows

A view is set up to display a node's contents. The node contains workflow moderation, like the published status.

To make a new change in the content and to preview it, the content is set to draft mode. Then, new content is added. Access unpublished module and shield module is set up so that business stakeholders could be sent a preview URL with username/password.

The view is not pulling in the changes to the node that was done after the node was published and was set up in draft mode. In other words revisions are not being pulled in by the view.

What needs to be done for the view so that a preview can be set up?